# Can AWS DMS be used for RDS Migrations from on-prem to the cloud without in bound network connectivity?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I'm setting up the migration of a mission-critical production (Oracle) Database from on-prem to AWS (Aurora Postgres). Because of security restrictions, it is not possible for any inbound traffic to reach the database server (or a proxy). Outbound traffic from on-prem has no restrictions.

I've been working with AWS DMS but everything seems to require that the replication server be running in AWS, and communicating interactively with the source database.

We're looking into setting up Site-to-Site VPN to facilitate inbound network connectivity, but this is going to take some time to get approved and deployed. Ideally, we'd like to set up some sort of DMS agent running locally to manage the migration from inside our network, bi-directionally synchronizing our database until the migration process is completed.

Is there an option I'm missing?

Comment: 'bi-directionally' - so is the issue something not running locally? you mention in bound is blocked? do you mean in one direction?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Honestly, that is probably a bit of extraneous info. It is my understanding that DMS supports keeping two DB's ( PG in RDS, and Oracle on-prem) synchronized. That is, changes to either DB would be reflected in the other. This is a critical part of our incremental cloud migration plan: Run both DB's, operationally, in parallel. That is the bi-directionality bit. As you mentioned, there is (currently) no inbound route to are our existing DB. Thus, optimally, the synchronization agent would run on-prem, not in AWS as is the only option I can find.